# XML Insert Performance into MYSQL

Tags: mysql, xml, performance, go, go-gorm

I have some code which inserts the records on the database:

The code is supposed to insert 15M records on the database, right now, it takes 60 hours on a AWS t2.large instance. I'm looking for ways to make the insert on the DB faster while also not duplicating records.

Do you guys have suggestions for me?

I'm using Gorm and MYSQL.

```
// InsertJob will insert job into database, by checking its hash.
func InsertJob(job XMLJob, oid int, ResourceID int) (Job, error) {
    db := globalDBConnection
    cleanJobDescription := job.Body

    hashString := GetMD5Hash(job.Title + job.Body + job.Location + job.Zip)
    JobDescriptionHash := GetMD5Hash(job.Body)
    empty := sql.NullString{String: "", Valid: true}
    j := Job{
        CurrencyID:              1, //USD

        //other fields here elided for brevity

        PrimaryIndustry: sql.NullString{String: job.PrimaryIndustry, Valid: true},
    }

    err := db.Where("hash = ?", hashString).Find(&j).Error
    if err != nil {
        if err.Error() != "record not found" {
            return j, err
        }

        err2 := db.Create(&j).Error
        if err2 != nil {
            log.Println("Unable to create job:" + err.Error())
            return j, err2
        }
    }

    return j, nil
}
```

Comment: If your hash isn’t the primary key you could create an index on it to speed up the WHERE queries. Batching inserts may also provide a speed up.

Comment: I agree, inserting N entries at a time instead of doing it one by one should give a huge increase in performance in case your DB is not on the same machine (because you'll need less communications over the network). You can also check multiple hashes at a time, and parse the output to figure out what is a duplicate and what is not.

Comment: Thanks @John I'll be sure to try this :)

Comment: @DmitryVerhoturov That's an awesome suggestion! I'll try that next

Comment: Show us the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the generated `INSERT` statements.  (@John - I agree; batching rows often give 10x speedup.)

Answer (score 0):

You can speed it up using using semaphore pattern.

https://play.golang.org/p/OxO8pNy3bc6

inspired from here.

https://gist.github.com/montanaflynn/ea4b92ed640f790c4b9cee36046a5383

Comment: We ended up dropping GORM and doing bulk inserts.

Comment: you should use gorm v2. it supports bulk inserts.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention!!! at the time of posting, Gorm V2 wasn't a thing...